# Visual Studio 2017 project referencing old version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I was using .Net Core 2.1.1, and recently updated the SDK to 2.1.401 (.Net Core Runtime 2.1.3). When i create a new project the version of **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App** under Dependencies > SDK is still 2.1.1. Looking at the properties of Dependencies > NuGet, the package is being referenced from *"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.app\2.1.1"*

I tried installing Package 2.1.3 using NuGet package manager, and it downloaded all dependencies from NuGet despite that i have 2.1.3 already installed on my machine.

How do i force existing / new project to use the latest version of packages from the SDK install ?

Comment: You are correct! I have checked this! same to me. May be this is a bug. Please report it here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, fyi .. here's the link to the issue that i've raised : https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to update the version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` manually in your project. 2.1.1 is perfectly fine. Your application will run on the latest 2.1.* framework installed on the machine.

If you publish a self-contained application, the tooling will automatically switch to the latest known version of 2.1.* at build time for the self-contained build only. (`-r win-x64` argument)

This may or may not change for the 2.2 or 3.0 releases, read/follow [this GitHub issue and thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3292) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the discussion link. I accept that i can work with 2.1.1, but what i failed to understand is why does VS references the package from NuGetFallBack folder and not from SDK when i explicitly specify version to the package. By the way, from the discussion what i understood is that providing explicit version of the package in .csproj is the way to go for now. Am i right ?

Comment: Right now I think it's better to remove the `Version=""` attribute / metadata completely for 2.1 and see if they implement changes in 2.2 or 3.0 (more likely in 3.0).

Comment: The idea of a "shared framework" is that the runtime provides the implementation but you only compile against the contract. The contract shouldn't (mustn't) change between patch releases and your app will run on the newest available patch anyway. Only for self-contained apps the reference is important (in addition to compile-time references, it will pull implementations) but again this can be managed via the SDK now ("latest known patch release")

Comment: It's now clear that it's a problem under discussion with the AspNet, and it has become subjective to decide if to use Version or not. I agree with you that for now it's not important to update the project, and hence will remove the Version. But, anyone looking for a self contained deployment might have to consider using the Version Attribute. Thanks for the clarifications !!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug as it has already been reported but for now this can be the solution.

In `ProjectName.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Can you please share the issue id, if you have it with you ? Thnx

Comment: setting RuntimeFrameworkVersion to 2.1.3 upgraded the Microsoft.NETCore.App to 2.1.3 ( on project reload ). But the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App remains 2.1.1 and setting it to 2.1.3 in project file makes NuGet to download 2.1.3.

Comment: @PraveenRai Okay let me check!

Comment: May be you didn't set this ` <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.3" />
</ItemGroup>` . I have checked. it works in my side.

Comment: Setting version=2.1.3 didnt pick the package from sdk, instead it downloads from Nuget, which should not happen.

Comment: Yeh! but this is temporary solution because this was not working as expected!

Comment: Ok ! I thought this will make the project to pick the latest package from SDK. Getting the package from nuget was already working. Do you have the issue id for this ? Anyways i have already raised an issue, plz refer my comment under the question. Thanks